# VueJS/ElementUI: Accessing the rows of an El-Table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using Element-UI along with VueJS for a project, and I've recently hit a wall.

For the needs of a specific function, I need to access the individual rows of an el-table component, preferably using $refs, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it.

EDIT:

I have a set of rows rendered within the table depending on information that comes from the server in the form of an array of objects. When the application receives the data, it parses the objects and nests them into corresponding groups if certain values are repeated, such as a product's id or the manufacturer's id. If the data is not repeated, it is left as is.

In one of the methods defined in the Vue component that calls el-table, I need to loop through the rows rendered inside the table in order to access their data and process a set of information.

I can access the table itself pretty easily once I set the ref attribute on it and call this.$refs, but I can't figure out how to access the rows themselves. I haven't found any way to set the ref attribute on the rows, either. I tried using pure JavaScript and jQuery and I managed to access the group of rows, but doing it this way doesn't allow me to access the data stored in the Vue elements.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you are trying to do

Comment: @Neil.Work Hey there. Sorry for the lack of information, I posted this when I was running short on time and had to be brief. I'll update the post with more details.

Comment: Why can’t you just loop the array you bind to the table?  What data would be in the row elements that would be different?

Comment: @Neil.Work, well I forgot to say this, but I also need access to the row so I can use the table specific method: **toggleRowExpansion**. It'd go something like this: **this.$refs.productsTable.toggleRowExpansion(row)**, but since I do not have access to the row, I can't make this work...

Comment: You can toggle the expansion just using the object from the array, here is a codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rXBRae?&editable=true

Comment: If you're still looking for an answer. I answered a similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644044/how-to-correctly-setup-links-in-an-element-ui-table-row-should-be-easy

Comment: Or are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612126/work-with-filtered-data-of-element-ui-table

Comment: @dreijntjens Ah, hey, thanks! It's been a while since I looked into this and I can't really remember how I worked around my issue, but I'm glad you shared the links. Those could definitely help me out in future projects. Cheers!