# Work with filtered data of Element UI table

Tags: element-ui

I would like to access the remaining data of a filtered `Element UI` `Table`.

Please see the example implementation on the `Element UI` website:
`Table Filter`: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table

Suppose I set the `Tag` filter to `Home`, the table would show two remaining columns.
Is there a way to access only the not filtered columns?
A simple example use case would be to get the number of remaining rows.

It was not yet possible for me to directly access the remaining data.
I tried to use the `filter-method` to collect the necessary data to filter the data myself.
Filtering would basically work, but resetting the filter doesn't trigger an event, so this approach is useless to me.

Do I miss something, does anyone have an idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the not filtered records.

Add a ref to the table like

```
<el-table ref="table">
```

Then you can access it in a method with:

```
this.$refs.table.tableData
```

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot!
Now I could also find it with the vue dev tools.